# <Asterisk>Is there any way to block B from hear A temporary

Tags: voip, asterisk

Extension A and B are both in meetme R. Extension C chanspy A with param(**qow**). so:
A can hear B, B can hear A.
A can hear C, C can hear A.
B cannot hear C, C cannot hear B.

Is there any way to block B from hear A ***temporary***. And when C hangup, B will be able to hear A again ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can kick off B to other confernce, after that bring back.

Or use mute/volume change via meetmeadmin.

You can do both using AMI.

Comment: I'm sorry I havn't described clearly.<br/>A, B, E, F, G, H are in meetme R. Suddenlly A have to tell C some important thing, he doesn't wannt other people to hear. And A cann't miss this important meetme.<br/>A have to listen to both meetme and C. Meetme shouldn't hear what A says temporary.

Comment: move A to enother meetme R2, connect R to R2(create new call), mute A in R2, wisper to B(enother call). after that move all back and close R2.

Comment: It seems will work, I'll try it. Thank you very much.